# Codeigniter activerecord query for multiple values with exact results

Tags: activerecord

I have a query for filtering products that are related to categories and subcategories and tags/attributes (color, lengths, connection etc) and i'm having problems getting exact results using $this->db->where_in("field",$array_of_tags);  is there another whey to this i haven't figured out ?
This is my function 
`public function get_public_products($limit_start = false, $limit_end = false, $categoria = false, $subcategoria = false , $tags = false){

```
    if(!$subcategoria){
        $this->db->select('*');
    }
    $this->db->from('products');
    if($categoria && !$subcategoria){
        $this->db->join('products_categories', 'products.familia = products_categories.codigo');
        $this->db->where('products_categories.slug',$categoria);
    }
    if($subcategoria && !$tags){
        $this->db->select('products.familia AS familia, products.subfamilia AS subfamilia, products.slug AS pslug, products_categories.slug AS cslug , products.nombre AS nombre, products_categories.name AS cname, products.codigo_producto AS codigo_producto');
        $this->db->join('products_categories', 'products.subfamilia = products_categories.codigo');         
        $this->db->where('products_categories.slug',$subcategoria);                 
    }

    if($tags){
        $this->db->select('products.familia AS familia, products.subfamilia AS subfamilia, products.slug AS pslug, products_categories.slug AS cslug , products.nombre AS nombre, products_categories.name AS cname, products.codigo_producto AS codigo_producto , products_tags_values.value AS tvalue, products_tags_values.slug AS tslug');
        $this->db->join('products_categories', 'products.subfamilia = products_categories.codigo'); 
        $this->db->where('products_categories.slug',$subcategoria); 

        $this->db->join('products_tags_values', 'products_tags_values.pid = products.codigo_producto');
        $tags_array = explode(",", $tags);
        $this->db->where_in('products_tags_values.slug',$tags_array);   

    }

    if($limit_start){
        $this->db->limit($limit_start, $limit_end); 
    }       

    $query = $this->db->get();
    return $query->result_array();      
}`
```

This works fine when i use `$this->db->where('products_tags_values.slug',"blue");` but not if i chane them like this for multiple tags. 
`$this->db->where('products_tags_values.slug',"blue");

$this->db->where('products_tags_values.slug',"20-m");`